# Spectral radius and power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following equation:

$$
M_{t+1}=(NK)^{t+1}M_0+((NK)^t+(NK)^{t-1}+\cdots+(NK)+I)NR
$$

which is:
\begin{align}
M_{t+1}=(NK)^{t+1}M_0+((NK)^{t+1}-I)((NK)-I)^{-1}NR
\end{align}

I want that $M_{t+1}$ should behave in such a way, that it goes exponential as $t$ increases. However, as $t$ approaches $\infty$, then $M_{t+1}$ should converge, i.e. its value should become constant, and independent of $t$.

In this context, what should be the value of the spectral radius of $NK$ that it behaves as mentioned. Will it really behave so?

1. I initially assumed that if the spectral radius of the matrix $NK$ is less than one, then, the given function will converge, because then it will become the following:

\begin{align}
 \lim_{t\to\infty} M_{t}=(I-NK)^{-1}NR 
\end{align}

But, in this case, the function converges at $t$=1 itself, and does not show initial exponential behavior.

2. If we take $NK$ such that the spectral radius of $NK$ is more than one, then it behaves exponential quickly, and never converges.
3. Currently, it is assumed that the matrix $N$, $K$ and $R$ are constant matrices. If you think that by making $K$ and $R$ a decreasing function in terms of $t$ (keeping $N$ constant), will help in achieving the desired behavior, please suggest that too.

Any guidance in this regard will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that you should have some initial exponential *growth* followed by convergence?

Comment: Yes @Ian Correct.

Comment: Initially exponential growth, and then M_{t+1} becomes constant as t goes very high.